# How ejabberd 13.10 server is better than ejabberd previous versions in terms of performance?

Tags: ejabberd

I am working in android application development using ejabberd-2.1.13 as a server for my android application. I heard that ejabberd-13.10 is better in performance compare to previous versions.So I installed ejabberd-13.10 in my ubuntu machine.To ensure performance of ejabberd-13.10 I did performance test for different ejabberd servers(ejabberd-2.1.13 & ejabberd-13.10) using fprof tool as described in following link.(http://carbonshaft.blogspot.in/2011/11/erlang-using-fprof-profiler-to-drive.html) .But I  get latest ejabberd server (ejabberd-13.10) show slow performance compare to ejabberd-2.1.13.Could you please advice how the ejabberd-13.10 server is better in performance?

Comment: The latest `ejabberd` release is [13.12](http://lists.jabber.ru/pipermail/ejabberd/2013-December/008223.html). Its release notes do not mention performance improvements though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

13.10 is better by the simple fact 2.1.x branch is [*officially* deprecated and abandoned](http://lists.jabber.ru/pipermail/ejabberd/2013-October/008173.html).

This means two simple things:

- No new version in the 2.1.x will be released.
- Bugs found in 2.1.13 might not get fixed.

Also I would suggest not *profiling* but rather *measuring the real-life performance* using a suitable tool, such as [`tsung`](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/).  The problem with profiling two *different* code bases is that you're comparing apples to oranges.  Things like memory consumption (declared to be greatly reduced in 13.x due to switching from strings to binaries) *do* count in real-world scenarios when you intend to host thousands of concurrent connections.  Also note that programs like `ejabbed` do really tend to be memory- and I/O-bound, not CPU-bound (the latter usually indicates you've managed to trigger a bug in the program or runtime) so mere profiling might not be indicative, only stress testing the staging or production server would.

Comment: I can check load balance by using tsung. But How can I check memory consumed by ejabberd -13.10 and ejabberd-2.1.13.

Comment: @BABUK, by running on the target server any monitoring tool you feel yourself comfortable with.  This might be as simple as `$ watch -n 5 grep -F VmRSS /proc/$(pgrep beam)/status`

Answer (score 0):

Starting with ejabberd 13.x, several optimisations have been performed:

- Optimization of the memory consumption.
- Optimization of the performance of some important modules, like pubsub.
- Better Multi User Chat performance and lower latency.
- Multicast routing optimization.

In term of performance, ejabberd 15.07 for example is 2 to 3 time more efficient on all the parameters: Memory, latency, CPU.